# PWA Launching The Safari Browser With A Certain URL

Tags: javascript, redirect, safari, progressive-web-apps

I was wondering if I could use something similar to

```
safari://https://google.com/
```

for my PWA to launch the safari browser. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You don't know for sure if Safari is installed. Do you want to use `window.open()`, which always opens your link in your pwa even when you've visited the website in the browser? I did workaround this by creating a subdomain for these specific urls, which won't be forced opened in my pwa

Comment: I want it to open in safari so I can make them add another pwa inside my pwa...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you specifically want to open it in Safari only? Because of the uncertainty around whether the browser of your choice is actually installed or not, by design there's currently no way to achieve this. PWA will open in the browser from which it was added to home screen and not the browser of your choice or even default browser of your device. If you still feel there's a valid use case for this requirement, file a bug by following [this link](https://web.dev/how-to-file-a-good-bug/).